# ¿Por qué no se envían los datos a mi base de datos?

Tags: php, html

tras varios intentos de enviar los datos de un formulario a una base de datos, me da el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined index: de in C:\xampp\htdocs\basadin\assets\external_php\send.php on line 7

Os dejo aquí el código de mi website.

```
    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="no" name="de" value="no">
        <label for="no">No</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="si" name="des" value="si" checked>
        <label for="si">Sí</label>
    </div>

    </div>
    <label for="button">
        <span class="s_button">Todos sus datos se encuentran asegurados.</span>
    </label>
    <input class="button" type="submit" id="button" name="button" value="Continuar" />
</form>
```

send.php

```
<?php 
include "data.php";

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$no = $_POST['de'];
$si = $_POST['des'];

$query = "INSERT INTO loco12(email, pass, no_, si_) VALUES('$email','$pass','$no','$si')";
```

Comment: Puedes imprimir al inicio del php el $_POST, con print_r($_POST)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si las opciones "si" o "no" son del mismo grupo, entonces estás empleando mal el "radio button" [Ver documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) (Observar que los tags `name` son el mismo en cada opción).

Como ya hay una opción seleccionada por default, no hay forma que el usuario envíe ese input vacío; pero si quitas el `ckecked`, entonces tendrías que controlarlo con un [radio required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8287947/1545868) o manejar una opción default en el PHP, con `isset($_POST['des'])`.

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" id="no" name="des" value="no">
    <label for="no">No</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="radio" id="si" name="des" value="si" checked>
    <label for="si">Sí</label>
</div>
```

Y en PHP

```
$des = $_POST['des']; // Esto tendrá: 'Si' o 'No'.
```

No tiene ningún sentido tener en una base de datos `si=si` y `no=no`, pero si algo como `seleccionado=Si` o `seleccionado=No` a según se haya escogido.

Comment: Genial, funciona y ahora lo entiendo perfectamente ¡muchas gracias! :D